# Is there a way to use Strength for the Perform Skill?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, skills, ability-scores, dnd-3e

How (if possible) would one utilize their Strength ability score with the Perform Skill? Be that in lieu of Charisma or in addition to it.

There are so many ways to shuffle the ability score that powers a skill, but my search-fu is failing me so I'm turning to the Stack for support.

Third Party is fine, my only requirement is published material for D&D 3rd edition or Pathfinder 1st Edition.

Comment: Well, there is the [Arnold Sports Festival](https://www.arnoldsports.com/).

Answer (score 6):

### No

Not for the Perform skill itself, not without using the Variant suggested on page 33 of the DMG:

> **VARIANT: SKILLS WITH DIFFERENT ABILITIES**
>
> Sometimes a check involves a character’s training (skill ranks) plus an
> innate talent (ability) not usually associated with that training. A skill
> check always includes skill ranks plus an ability modifier, **but you can use a different ability modifier from normal if the character is in a situation where the normal key ability does not apply**.
>
> [...]
>
> These sorts of unusual situations are always handled on a case-by-case
> basis, and only as exceptions. The vast majority of the time, use the
> normal key ability.
>
> Remember that when you change the way a skill works in this fashion, you should dictate when the change comes into play — it’s not up
> to a player to make this sort of decision. Players may try to rationalize
> why they should get to use their best ability score modifier with a skill
> that doesn’t normally use that ability, but you shouldn’t allow this sort
> of rule change unless you happen to agree with it.

### BaB can help

However, you can get **half your BaB** as a bonus by choosing the Weapon Drill subskill:

> **PERFORM (WEAPON DRILL) (Cha)**
>
> You are skilled in quick, flashy movements of a weapon and
> can put on a display that shows off your prowess in combat.
> This category of the Perform skill covers any sort of
> weapon display, such as twirling a sword or flipping a dagger
> from hand to hand. Despite the skill’s name, you can use it
> when unarmed by demonstrating difficult martial arts techniques or shadow boxing against an imaginary opponent.
>
> **Check**: Unlike other categories of the Perform skill, your
> prowess with the weapon (indicated by your base attack
> bonus) is an important factor in how good your Perform
> (weapon drill) skill is. **Apply half your base attack bonus
> (rounded down) as a circumstance bonus on Perform
> (weapon drill) checks**. Your Charisma modifier also applies,
> as with any Perform check. If you aren’t proficient with the
> weapon you’re using, you take the –4 nonproficiency penalty
> on Perform (weapon drill) checks.

(*Complete Warrior, p121-122*)

### Priming your audience

Five levels of the [Exemplar Prestige Class](https://www.realmshelps.net/charbuild/classes/prestige/general/exemplar.shtml) gives you access to Persuasive Performance:

> **Persuasive Performance (Ex)**: Starting at 5th level, an exemplar can use her skill artistry to improve the attitudes of NPCs. To do this, the NPCs must observe her using one of the skills to which she has applied skill artistry. Treat this as a Diplomacy check made to influence NPC attitudes, but replace the Diplomacy check with a check using the chosen skill.

This allows you to use any skill previously chosen, including one for which you CAN use Strength, in place of Diplomacy.

This allows you to make your audience Helpful, or possibly if you can reach [Epic levels of Diplomacy](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/skills.htm#diplomacy), Fanatic:

> **Helpful**   Will take risks to help you     Protect, back up, heal, aid
>
> **Fanatic**   Will give life to serve you     Fight to the death against overwhelming odds, throw self in front of onrushing dragon

Even if you can't get directly get your Strength bonus to Perform, using Perform in front of an audience very keen on helping and backing you up is likely to improve the result significantly.

Just remember to [jump](https://web.archive.org/web/20150608054519/http://community.wizards.com/forum/previous-editions-character-optimization/threads/1141886) before singing, and you're golden. ;)

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, when you use the Variant Rule with your DM's approval

For example, you could perform feats of strength as your performance -- bending bars, lifting heavy weights, ripping thick tomes apart.

The DM can and should limit this to uses of the skill where it makes sense: where you have an audience interested in such feats of strength, you have the right equipment to perform with, etc. It would not generally apply, for example, you could not enter a bardic performance contest for poetry using your strength (unless you came up with a really good explanation that your DM would agree to).

The variant rule states

> > **VARIANT: SKILLS WITH DIFFERENT ABILITIES**
>
> Sometimes a check involves a character’s training (skill ranks) plus an
> innate talent (ability) not usually associated with that training. A skill
> check always includes skill ranks plus an ability modifier, **but you can use a different ability modifier from normal if the character is in a situation where the normal key ability does not apply**. [...]
>
> These sorts of unusual situations are always handled on a case-by-case
> basis, and only as exceptions. The vast majority of the time, use the
> normal key ability.
>
> Remember that when you change the way a skill works in this fashion, you should dictate when the change comes into play — it’s not up to a player to make this sort of decision. Players may try to rationalize why they should get to use their best ability score modifier with a skill that doesn’t normally use that ability, but **you shouldn’t allow this sort of rule change unless you happen to agree with it**.